# SQL date question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a question. I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a field column. I have for example the Following dates:

```
1/1/2001
5/5/2004
8/5/2009
10/7/2011
5/5/2012
1/13/2014
```

Id like to be able to show all dates >= the current date (`7/29/2011`) as well as largest table date that is < current date. In this example, the result would be all dates `>= 8/5/2009`.

Can someone help guide me please??

Comment: I edited the description to better describe what I believe he's looking for.

Comment: Will you please clarify the requirements?  When you say "date behind the current date," do you mean "yesterday"?  Or do you mean, "the most recent date in the table that is <= today?"

Comment: In addition to which RDBMS you use (e.g. SQL Server) could you please specify which version? Also is the data type date/datetime/smalldatetime or is it stored as char/varchar? And can you show your expected results in tabular format instead of in a word problem?

Comment: Please can you add the expected result for your example dates, thanks

Comment: table structure? Are these stored as varchar or as real dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to include the date prior to the current date.  GETDATE() will get the current date (with time).  If you're alright with that, then this should work.  Otherwise, you may have to parse out just the date from GETDATE()

```
SELECT TheDate
FROM DateTable
WHERE TheDate >= (SELECT MAX(TheDate) FROM DateTable WHERE TheDate < GETDATE())
```

This gets all dates greater than or equal to the most recent date before the current date.

Comment: Yes, this is much close to what the OP seems to be wanting.

Answer (score 4):

```
select max(date) [date] from table where date < getdate()
union 
select date from table where date >= getdate()
```

Comment: this would work, but it seems a solution without union could be better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand, but this looks like a BETWEEN the relevant dates. Or is there something more I am missing?

Comment: I think he's looking to query only the date which immediately precedes the current date, as well as every date after the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called DateTable and your field is called TheDate, do it like this:

```
SELECT TheDate
FROM DateTable
WHERE TheDate >= DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE())
```

Good luck!

Comment: i believe he wants the first entry before the current date, not necessarily the day before (so he wants 8/5/09 returned, which wouldn't in your query)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the SQL server you're using. In postgres, for example, you need something like

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE date_field >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
```

But other SQL servers have different ways to specify "yesterday"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM dates d1
  LEFT JOIN dates d2 ON d1.Date < d2.Date AND d2.Date < GETDATE()
WHERE d2.Date IS NULL
```

Explanation:

> Select every date for which there does not exist a date that is both earlier than today and later than the one being inspected.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of guessing here based on loose narrative and unknown data types.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATE);

INSERT @t SELECT '20010101'
UNION ALL SELECT '20040505'
UNION ALL SELECT '20090805'
UNION ALL SELECT '20111007'
UNION ALL SELECT '20120505'
UNION ALL SELECT '20140113';

DECLARE @now DATE = SYSDATETIME();

WITH t AS
(
    SELECT d, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d)
    FROM @t
)
SELECT t.d
    FROM t LEFT OUTER JOIN t AS x
    ON t.rn = x.rn - 1
    WHERE COALESCE(x.d, @now) >= @now
    ORDER BY t.d;
```